# get Compilation file after resolving templates and scope?

Tags: c++

There are many things that c++ compiler do on its own. But is there is any way to get what it does. I mean if there is macro and we want to see what is the preprocessing output there is an option `-E` in g++. But is there an other options for the following things:

1) Using keyword

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
   cout<<"hello"<<endl;
 }
```

The above code is understand by the compiler in the following way.

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
   std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}
```

Is there any way that I give compiler some input like first code and get the second code?

2) templates

```
 #include<iostream>
 template<class T>
 class name{
   public:
      T x; 
 };
 int main(){
   name<int> n;
   return 0;
 }
```

The above code will expand for a class name with int as template type. But is there any way I can get that definition of class?

3) typedef keyword

My last doubt is about typedef. Is there any way to get the output with the replaced meaning of typdefed value.

```
   typedef int fun;
```

Now if we use fun its equivalent to int.

```
   fun x;
```

The above line is understand by the compiler in the following way:

```
   int x;
```

but is there any option of g++ to get that?

The using keyword syntax for typedef statement is `using fun=int` but can we get the same output as desired by me.

I am currently working on a project which take c++ file as input and get all the details of it converted to json. And my problem is these aliasing syntax which are useful for programmer but currently causing me a great problem.

Comment: https://cppinsights.io/ does parts of what you want

Comment: You're probably better off letting someone else do the hideously difficult task of parsing c++, e.g. [clang AST](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) or [CastXML](https://github.com/CastXML/CastXML)

Comment: Is there any tool in g++ environment. I dont want to switch compilers since most of source code are ready according to g++ norms.

Comment: there's [gccxml](https://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) but it hasn't been maintained for a while

Comment: sounds like gcc is reluctant to share its AST https://lwn.net/Articles/629259/

Comment: How much time can you afford spending on your project? I won't be surprised if you need many years full-time!

Comment: I need couple of month maybe because most of the time I tried to use free things. And I know about the project I took it takes parsing c++ then passing some inputs to some sort of turing and lastly disassemble the object files for backtracking in total work is alot if I go personally on every module but c++ have tools. And thanks for advice of cppinsights and gccxml.

Answer (score 1):

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you cannot get some AST in C++ friendly format (there is no [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) for that).

However, GCC is able to dump most of its internal representations (e.g. [GENERIC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html) or [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) or [SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA.html)), in some textual format (often inspired by C). Read about GCC [developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) and try some of the many `-fdump*` options. For example `-fdump-tree-all` would dump hundreds of various dump files.

[Template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) expansion is not (e.g; in C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) exactly defined as some AST transformation and C++ is sadly not an [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language (look perhaps into [Terra](http://terralang.org/) if you want something closer to that).

If you believe that template expansion can usually be expressed as some C++ to (simpler) C++ transformation for your case (in general it is false since [C++ templates are Turing complete](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/11/c-templates-are-turing-complete.html); see also [this](https://rtraba.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/cppturing.pdf) and  think of recursive or [variadic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) templates) you might consider developing some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to do that. It would take several months (or even years) of your time.

> I am currently working on a project which take c++ file as input and get all the details of it converted to json.

That sounds as a good use case for some GCC plugin (be sure to write it for a *recent* version of GCC, e.g. [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in august 2018; GCC plugins are tied to a particular version of GCC, and GCC has progressed even recently w.r.t. plugins). However, parsing C++ is complex (whatever technology you use: GCC or Clang) and it will take a lot of work (probably much more than a year).

> And my problem is these aliasing syntax

Believe me, that is not your only (or most important) problem. **C++ is really difficult to parse**.

PS. My old (and obsolete) [GCC MELT documentation](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) pages might contain useful slides and links.

Comment: well I thanks for so much information but can tell if there is any way to get some tools for the work I need I did try cppinsight and gccxml but still the work is alot in parsing even if I use the grammer c++ give in there documentation but it is till ambiguos and will result errors.

Comment: I tried to explain you that there is no easy way to achieve what you want. It takes years of work (whatever C++ compiler you base your work upon: GCC, Clang, ...). The real issue is the complexity of C++.